# Are expired time-based triggers deleted automatically, or should they be manually removed?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I set triggers in Google Apps Script programmatically to defer fetching data for some minutes while the job is being processed elsewhere.

I have noted that in Script Editor's "view current script's triggers" old (expired) triggers persist - I suspect that they also count against the max amount of triggers limit.

Will Google Apps Script delete these expired triggers or do I have to go through the list of triggers and delete expired ones? If yes, does somebody want to share a code example? (This should also be included in the docs, I suggest).

I create triggers by using .at

```
   var d = new Date();
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 5);
  
  try {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("retrieveOrder")
      .timeBased()
      .at(d)
      .create();
  } catch(e) {
    sendErrorMail(e + " \n \n"  + "Date: " + d);
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chucked the Trigger's unique id along with a timestamp of when it is set to expire into the ScriptDb. Then I clear it with this cludge:

```
/**
 * @param {ScriptDbInstance} db
 */
function clearExpiredTimeTriggers(db){

  var now = new Date();
  var nts = now.getTime();
  var res = db.query({trigId:db.anyValue(), trigExpiration: db.lessThan(nts)});
  var expiredTriggers = [];
  while (res.hasNext()){
    var item = res.next();
    expiredTriggers.push(item.trigId);
    db.remove(item);
  }

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    if (expiredTriggers.indexOf(triggers[i].getUniqueId()) > -1){
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This method is not full proof because of the +/- 15 min on actual execution time of your trigger (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#at(Date)), so when you add the above timestamp, make sure to add an appropriate 15 min leeway.

Answer (score 3):

If you know where it's being called from then you can just delete by handler function ...
The function "updateGmailPhotoFromDriveBatcher" is called then calls itself

```
// this is called by a daily trigger. I don't want it deleted
function runPhotoUpdates() {
  // NEEDS to be a separate fnc so it doesn't get deleted
  updateGmailPhotoFromDriveBatcher()
}

// this function does a job, then reschedules itself until a blank is returned
function updateGmailPhotoFromDriveBatcher() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //fetches the   spreadsheet that the script is running in
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Groups");


  var sgfrom = sheet.getRange(10, 21).getValue(); 
  var npt = sheet.getRange(11, 21).getValue();  

  var oneJob = oneBatch(npt,sgfrom)
  var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  // WRITE THE new values; oneJob[0] is blank when completed; npt is a next page token of something that times out if you run the whole user base
  sheet.getRange(10, 21).setValue(oneJob[1]);
  sheet.getRange(11, 21).setValue(oneJob[0]);
  sheet.getRange(12, 21).setValue(oneJob[2]);
  sheet.getRange(13, 21).setValue(currTime)


  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  if (oneJob[0] != "") {
  // SCHEDULE NEW JOB

   ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateGmailPhotoFromDriveBatcher")
           .timeBased()
           .at(new Date(currTime+(20*1000))) // 20 seconds from NOW
           .create();
   } else { // FINISHED
      // KILL TRIGGERS
      deleteTriggers()
   }

}

function deleteTriggers() { // cleans up the triggers made above
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
       var thf = triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()   //String    Returns the function that will be called when the trigger fires.
       // if it's the one I kept making above
       if (thf == "updateGmailPhotoFromDriveBatcher") {
            ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
       }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You had to delete the triggers. Look at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events#ScriptService) for an example